# How to get a list of subsequence as output?

Tags: python

The output is not a string nor a list it is just sequence of letters and words. Can someone tell me how to convert the output into a list ?

```
def find_all_subsequence(string):
    combs = []
    for l in range(1, len(string)+1):
        combs.append(list(itertools.combinations(string, l)))
    for c in combs:
        for t in c:
            print("".join(t), end=" ")
```

Comment: An explanation of what this function is supposed to be doing along with some sample data would help your question.

Comment: Clearly you understand how to create a list and append items to it. Do you understand what `return` does in Python? If you do, then the only remaining part is to think about what items you're putting into the list, and then actually do the `return`ing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the sequence of letters and words to a list, and you can return the list

Example

```
import itertools
 
def find_all_subsequence(STR):
    combs = []
    result = []
    for l in range(1, len(STR)+1):
        combs.append(list(itertools.combinations(STR, l)))
    for c in combs:
        for t in c:
           result.append(''.join(t))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_all_subsequence('abc'))
```